# pine script - ADX indication modification

Tags: pine-script

I would like to do a small modification on the ADX indicator but my skills with programming are limited:

```
    //@version=4
study("Average Directional Index", shorttitle="ADX LP", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
adxlen = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing")
dilen = input(14, title="DI Length")
dirmov(len) =>
    up = change(high)
    down = -change(low)
    plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
    minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
    truerange = rma(tr, len)
    plus = fixnan(100 * rma(plusDM, len) / truerange)
    minus = fixnan(100 * rma(minusDM, len) / truerange)
    [plus, minus]

adx(dilen, adxlen) =>
    [plus, minus] = dirmov(dilen)
    sum = plus + minus
    adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adxlen)

sig = adx(dilen, adxlen)

plot(sig, color=color.red, title="ADX")
```

I would like to achieve something similar to the image below:
[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz34L.jpg)

the idea is to have two lines, one at 20 other at 30. above the 30 to have green, between 30 and 20 to have blue, and below 20 to have red.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary conditional operators directly in `plot`

```
plot(sig,color = sig > 30 ? color.green : sig < 20 ? color.red : color.grey)
```

you can also use a variable for the color in order to save space

```
col = sig > 30 ? color.green : sig < 20 ? color.red : color.gray
plot(sig,color = col)
```